# Index position of an element

Tags: python, list, algorithm

So, I have this code,How to find the specific index of zero element?

```
arr =[1,0,2,0]
for i in arr:
    if i <=0:
        print(list(arr).index(i))
    else:
        print("greater")
```

prints:

```
greater
1
greater
1
```

target:

```
greater
1
greater
3
```

Comment: ```index()``` will always only return the first occurence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `enumerate()`, You will get both index and value at the same time. Compare value is greater than 0 or not.

```
arr = [1, 0, 2, 0]
for i, val in enumerate(arr):
    if val > 0:
        print('Greater!')
    else:
        print(i)
```

*Output*

```
Greater!
1
Greater!
3
```

Comment: I would like see : `print('Greater!' if val > 0 else i)`

Comment: @ansev Yes it also works and more comprehensive

Answer (score 0):

in python 3 you can get all the index with the following line.

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda enum_val: enum_val[1] > 0, enumerate(arr))))
```